# c# DataGridView.DataSource = BindingList Doesn't Work

Tags: c#, datagridview, bindinglist

I create a binding list `BindingList<RunData>` and pass it through `CustomMessageBox.Show()` but the `DataGridView` doesn't display the list elements.

```
public partial class CustomMessageBox : Form
{
    #region Fields.

    private static CustomMessageBox customMessageBox;

    private static String selectedDateTime;

    #endregion

    #region Properties.

    internal String SelectedDateTime
    { get { return CustomMessageBox.selectedDateTime; } }

    #endregion

    #region Constructors.

    private CustomMessageBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();            
    }

    #endregion

    #region Methods.

    internal static DialogResult Show(BindingList<RunData> dataGridViewData)
    {
        CustomMessageBox.customMessageBox = new CustomMessageBox();
        CustomMessageBox.customMessageBox.dataGridViewRunData.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
        CustomMessageBox.customMessageBox.dataGridViewRunData.DataSource = dataGridViewData;            
        return CustomMessageBox.customMessageBox.ShowDialog();            
    }

    #endregion
}

internal class RunData
{
    #region Fields.

    private String dateTime;

    private String name;

    private String product;

    private String result;

    #endregion

    #region Properties.

    internal String DateTime
    { get { return this.dateTime; } }

    internal String Name
    { get { return this.name; } }

    internal String Product
    { get { return this.product; } }

    internal String Result
    { get { return this.result; } }

    #endregion

    #region Constructors.

    internal RunData(String dateTime, String name, String product, String result)
    {
        this.dateTime = dateTime;
        this.name = name;
        this.product = product;
        this.result = result;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

I have never used `BindingList` before but from the examples I found online it looks like I did everything OK. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

**EDIT**

I'm using .NET 2.0 if that makes any difference.

Comment: Aren't you missing a .Bind() function after you set the datasource in the show function??

Comment: Try calling `ResetBindings()` after setting the `DataSource`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my testing I have found that the model class (i.e. RunData) and or properties should be Public not internal.

I created a sample class and did the same setup you have with your grid. It failed with internal properties and class. Once I made it public it was fine.

```
  public class RunData
  {
        #region Fields.

        private String dateTime;

        private String name;

        private String product;

        private String result;

        #endregion

        #region Properties.

        public String DateTime
        { get { return this.dateTime; } }

        public String Name
        { get { return this.name; } }

        public String Product
        { get { return this.product; } }

        public String Result
        { get { return this.result; } }

        #endregion

        #region Constructors.

        public RunData(String dateTime, String name, String product, String result)
        {
            this.dateTime = dateTime;
            this.name = name;
            this.product = product;
            this.result = result;
        }

        #endregion
  }
```

Comment: Yep, that worked. Strange, I really want to keep it internal. Oh well.